# Memcached creates three keys every 60 seconds

Tags: apache, tomcat, memcached, railo, lucee

I have something occurring I don't quite understand and it may or may not be related to Memcached. My current setup is three tomcat nodes all on the same machine load balanced by Apache HTTP 2.4 with Lucee 4.5 running on each node. I am using Memcached in a virtual machine as a session store.

Everything seems to be working great. However I noticed when I was looking at the contents of the Memcached items that every 60 seconds like clockwork there are new keys added based on the number of nodes I am running. So if I have all three nodes running, every 60 seconds there will be three keys added to the cache with my initial session key still there like it should be. In the image below you will see that the very first `stats cachedump 12 100` it lists an item, that is my initial session right after making my first request.

[image]

Because there are the same amount of keys added every minute that there are nodes running it makes me wonder if it is a setting in Apache or Tomcat that I have wrong or if what I am seeing is common for Memcached (doubtful). My guess would be Tomcat but I have nothing to go on and all of my searches for this lead no where so I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction on solving this. It might not be that big of deal but it seems like unnecessary data is getting stored when it doesn't need to be.

Below is a snippet of the proxy area in my Apache configuration that deals with the load balancing

```
<Proxy balancer://nodes>
    BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:5009 loadfactor=5
    BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:6009 loadfactor=5
    BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:7009 loadfactor=5

    # BalancerMember ajp://192.168.56.101:8009 route=node1 loadfactor=5
    # BalancerMember ajp://192.168.56.102:8009 route=node2 loadfactor=5
    # BalancerMember ajp://192.168.56.103:8009 route=node3 loadfactor=5
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)?$ balancer://nodes/$1$2
```

Comment: Sounds like you have 3 new sessions being created every minute.  Use Fusion Reactor to see where the requests are coming from.  Probably a heartbeat monitor that doesn't return cookies.  You can detect it and reduce the session timeout to 0 on those requests.

Comment: You were definitely on the right track! It was a scheduled task I had setup in Lucee, I honestly had no idea that it was still set to run on development. Now I just have to figure out how to prevent it from creating a new session on every request.

Comment: Turn session management off in Application.cfc for that request if the site won't error.  You can detect it via IP, URL, etc.  If you need the site to run and it requires session, set the timeout to 0 like I suggested above.  It should time out from the cache quickly.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1083-coldfusion-session-management-and-spiders-bots.htm